# Автоматизированная проверка правильности ввода почты?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Как написать unit-test для функции, которая проверят правильность введенного пользователем e-mail?

```
def email_check():
    email = input('Enter your e-mail: ')
    check = re.search(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+, email')
    if check:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

Comment: @luminant, Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: А вы гуглить пробовали? У меня первая ссылка - на офдоки, вторая - про использование юнит-тестов (на хабре). Вам этого мало будет?

И откуда вопрос? Не с яндекса случайно? ) Так если вы тестовые вопросы сюда выносите, то может и пробовать не стоит? ))

Comment: да, именно оттуда. просто это единственный вопрос, на который я затрудняюсь ответить. и я не выношу вопросы сюда, я просто прошу маленькую подсказку, чтобы потом от нее отталкиваться. мне важно чтобы я понимал, что делаю, поэтому я не прошу чтобы работу сделали за меня.

Comment: @luminant, юнит-тест - это проверка какого-то блока кода заранее сформированным инпутом на то, что он будет выдавать правильный вывод (также заранее определенный). Другими словами, требуется напихать в эту функцию гору валидных имейлов и мусора и убедиться, что где надо выдается true, а где надо - false.  
Дальше уже смотрите доки, я их пересказывать не буду.

Comment: @luminant, блин... Если это единственный вопрос, на который вы затрудняетесь ответить, то в чем трудность сначала поискать что-нить про эти юнит-тесты?

[Вот пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/177943/) - одна из первых строчек гугла. Вас чем-то результаты гугла не устраивают? Хотя судя по всему вам следует сначала вообще что-нить про тесты почитать, не обязательно питоновские.

Требования написания юнит-теста связано с тем, что они хотят увидеть не ваши знания о них, а ваши умения в их написании. Например для функции sqrt они ожидают увидеть такие примеры как 9, 5, -10, 999....99, "йцу" и т.д.

Comment: Поэтому будет очень странно, когда окажется, что ваши тестовые юнит-тесты были такими замечательными, что покрыли почти все (если даже не все) возможные случаи, а на деле вы тестируете самые простые случаи.

Для мыла, я так думаю, ожидают проверки типа "test.ru@", "@test.ru", "@test@test.ru", "te@test@test.ru", "qw#e@test.ru", "test@test", "test@test.test", "test@te#s.ru" и т.д.

Comment: У вас в коде пара проблем:

1) Не там кавычка:

    re.search(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+, email')

надо:

    re.search(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+', email)

2) как вы будете проверять тестами это:

    email = input('Enter your e-mail: ')

Делать перенаправление с файла? Эту строчку необходимо вынести за пределы функции, передавать полученное мыло в функцию и она должна не печатать что-то, а возвращать, например, True или False

3) WTF???? Почему эти email у вас проходят валидацию???

email_check('@as@test.ru')
email_check('@as@test.')
email_check('@as@t')
email_check('as@tes#t.ru')
email_check('as@tes,t.ru')